# CSS Working out equal heights

Tags: html, css, height, width

I have the following html and I am very confused about the following:

- The `.rowNumber` & the `.title` will be the same height throughout all three boxes
- The `.rowNumberItems` will not have the same amount of content in each column

How can I using CSS equal the columns so that my `.button div` is equal throughout all columns?

My columns are `height:200px; by width:195px;`

**Example Column :**

```
<div id="priceTable">
 <div class="rowOne">
  <p class="title">Name</p>
 <ul class="rowOneItems">
  <li>Custom Design</li>
 </ul>
   <div class="button"><a href="#">Buy Now</a></div>    
 </div> <!-- Column One --> 
</div>
```

**Current CSS:**

```
#priceTable{
    width:780px;
    height:230px;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:gray;
}
.rowOne, .rowTwo, .rowThree{
    float:left;
    height:225px;
    width:195px;
    margin:0 40px 0 0;
    background:red;
}

#priceTable .title{
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    color:#000;
}

#priceTable .button{
    background:green;
    background:url('../images/button.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: @BenjaminUdinktenCate I have chucked up my current CSS

Comment: wait so what do you want it to do?

Comment: @MagicDev I just want the .button div to be aligned and equal and not dependent on whats within the items ul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/ZJhPq/

Add the following CSS:

```
.rowOne, .rowTwo, .rowThree {
    position: relative;
}

#priceTable .button {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Also give that `#priceTable .button` a defined height and width.

Answer (score 0):

Could you set the .rowNumberItems to certain height and overflow: hidden? Once the height of the rowNumberItems is fixed, the button locations would be equal.

```
.rowOneItems{height:200px;overflow:hidden;}
```

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/3bmrZ/